# FileField in Django does not send file to its form request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a Django form where I upload an image through an input type file.

```py
class Form(forms.Form):
    photo = forms.FileField(
        label="Photo", widget=forms.FileInput(
            attrs={
                'class': 'form-control',
            }
        )
    )
```

I wrote the next view:

```py
def upload(request):
    context = {}
    
    if 'photo' in request.POST:
        form = Form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES["photo"])
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    else:
        form = Form()
    
    context['form'] = form
    
    return render(request, 'app/upload.html', context)

def handle_uploaded_file(file):
    with open('app/upload/'+file.name, 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in file.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

When I send the form the request does not recieve any file, even if I loaded a file before.
I am able to show by javascript jpeg files loaded when the field has changed. So the field is loading files but is not sending theme in the request.

Form does not check the validation `form.is_valid():` it says it is required even when I have uploaded a file .jpeg
Error shown in `print(form.errors)`:
`<ul class="errorlist"><li>photo<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>`
I leave my template form here:

```
        <form action="" method="post" id="search_face_form" style="width: 100%;">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="input-group-sm mb-4">
                        <label for="floatingInput">Archivo de búsqueda</label>
                        {{ search_form.face }}
                        {{ search_form.face.errors }}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img id="search_face_img" src="{% static 'cameras_admin/img/not_found.jpg' %}" style="display: none; max-height: 25vh;">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                    <div class="input-group-sm mb-4" >
                        <br>
                        <input type="submit" value="BUSCAR" style="width: 100%;" class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-block">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you change the form to the following it will accept files `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, that's a requirement for all forms which should accept files. Your first line in the template should look like this:
`<form action="" method="post" id="search_face_form" style="width: 100%;" enctype="multipart/form-data">`